# Add text end of specific line

Tags: ansible

I have a `/etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf` file with this block:

```
[rhsm]
# Content base URL:
baseurl=https://satellite.bcnconsulting.com
```

I want to check whether the line from `baseurl` ends with `/pulp/repos` or not. In case it doesn't add it to the end of the line.

The end result should be:

```
[rhsm]
# Content base URL:
baseurl=https://satellite.bcnconsulting.com/pulp/repos
```

For now I have,

```
- name: Check if baseurl in rhsm.conf is correct
  shell: "grep -nr baseurl /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf | grep -nr /pulp /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: result

- name: If it has not the /pulp/repos ending add it
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf
    line: '/pulp/repos'
    regexp: 'baseurl'
  when: result.stdout == ""
```

But this is just removing the line and writing `/pulp/repos`.

How can I accomplish to put it just after the last letter of the line?

Answer (score 1):

That is the problem [regex "backreferences"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs) are designed to solve

```yaml
- name: If it has not the /pulp/repos ending add it
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf
    line: '\1/pulp/repos'
    regexp: '^(baseurl=https://satellite.bcnconsulting.com)$'
    backrefs: yes
  when: result.stdout == ""
```